# String- Finding Null Value

Tags: java, string, null

I need to find null value occuring inside a string. For Example

```
String x= "isPay=false, isAlreadyRented=false, differenceBetweenStartTimeandNow=, thumbnailUrl=http://";
char strline2[] = x.toCharArray();
for (i = pos + 50; strline2[i] != '=' && i < strline2.length - 1; i++)
    ;
i = i + 1;
for (i = i; i < strline2.length - 284; i++) {
    if (strline2[i] == ',') {
        for (i = i; strline2[i] != '=' && i < strline2.length - 1; i++)
            ;
        i = i + 1;
        br_output.write("\t");
    }
    if (strline2[i] != ',' && strline2[i] != '=')
        br_output.write(strline2[i]);
}
```

from this I'm traversing till `=` , extract the values between `=` and `,` and store it in a file. So when there is no value, for example `differenceBetweenStartTimeandNow=,` it should write as `NULL` in the file. Can any one help me on this.

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: 1)Please format your code properly, it's not readable (2)Why are different values assigned to `i` in every line, but never used for any calculation?  What does `i` denote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
String x= "isPay=false, isAlreadyRented=false, differenceBetweenStartTimeandNow=, thumbnailUrl=http://";
x = x.replaceAll("=,",  "=NULL,");
```

This will replace all the empty values i.e. =, with =NULL, and then you can continue with your logic of extracting the value and storing it in the file

I hope this helps

Comment: "Id:null sourceType:ENTITY title:Episodes: Friends callSign:null channelNumber:null" same problem with tis string also, can you help with tis prasanth. "title:" value should be written as "null"

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(strline2[i] == '=' && strline2[i+1] == ','){
   r_output.write("NULL");
   continue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) as shown below:

```
        String[] strline2 = x.split("=*,");

        for (int i = 0; i < strline2.length; i++)
        {
            int index = strline2[i].indexOf('=');
            if(index < 0)
                br_output.write("NULL");                
            else
                br_output.write(strline2[i].substring(index+1, strline2[i].length()));
        }
```